# Проблема со шрифтом на сайте

Tags: html, оптимизация-сайтов

Вот с такой проблемкой столкнулся. На обычном домене, который предоставляют сайт шрифт выглядит нормально, как и должно быть, а на подключенном домене шрифт меняется на другой, побольше размером. Проблема в:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300italic,400italic,700italic,400,300,700&amp; subset=all' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Не хочет читать стиль на домене с протоколом https:// почему-то.

Comment: Для всех гугло-URL-ов рекомендуется использовать https, даже в том случае, если у вас сайт на http.

Comment: Рекомендую все шрифты на сайтах складывать локально. Вспомним когда роскомнадзор пытался заблокировать телеграмм, и не было доступа к гуглу - множество сайтов не грузило шрифты, т.к. гугл был заблокирован. Дел на 10 минут, но не будет казусов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда появился протокол "https", необходимо было в ссылке на фон прописать этот же протокол:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300italic,400italic,700italic,400,300,700&amp; subset=all' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```